# Como puedo agrupar mis registros por nombre en Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Esta es mi consulta SQL como podria agrupar por solo por los nombres para recuperar el Top de articulos vendidos

```
SELECT
A.ART_DESCRIPCION,
SUM(VD.VD_CANTIDAD),
SUM(VD.VD_TOTAL_GS)
FROM VENTAS V, VENTAS_DETALLE VD, CLIENTE C, ARTICULO A
WHERE
V.VEN_NRO = VD.VD_NRO
AND
V.VEN_CLIEN = C.CLI_CODIGO
AND
VD.VD_ARTICULO = A.ARTI_CODIGO

GROUP BY A.ART_DESCRIPCION, VD.VD_CANTIDAD, VD.VD_TOTAL_GS

ORDER BY VD.VD_CANTIDAD DESC
```

Comment: Porque agregaste los campos que sumas en el group by? con poner solo la descripcion alcanza.

Comment: Porque me genera el siguiente error si no lo tiene: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: Necesitas poner en el GROUP BY los campos que pones en el SELECT **para los que no usas funciones de agregación** (como SUM). En este caso, solo `A.ART_DESCRIPCION`.

Answer (score 1):

Tu primer error es incluir en la clausula `group by` campos por los que en realidad no deseas agrupar. Deja solamente el campo de la descripción en el agrupador.

El segundo error, es que intentas ordenar por el campo de la cantidad, pero ese campo no existe en el resultado, y por tanto no puedes ordenar por el. El que existe en el resultado es el *agregado* de la sumatoria de las cantidades. Puedes ordenar por ese campo si quieres ir del más vendido al menos vendido.

Estamos en 2018, hace mucho las bases de datos cumplen con los mínimos del estándar SQL, pero tu sigues escribiendo queries al estilo de versiones *demasiado* antiguas. Te sugiero aprender y escribir queries utilizando la sintaxis del inner join, que son mucho más fáciles de entender.

Finalmente, tu error más grave, es que no estás entendiendo el query que escribes. Sé que probablemente te estás basando en un query que ya existe y haciéndole adaptaciones. Eso está bien, todos lo hemos hecho y es parte del aprendizaje, pero debes esforzarte en entender hasta el último detalle del query si quieres mejorar tus habilidades en SQL.

En este, por ejemplo el hecho que hayas dejado la referencia a la tabla `cliente`, cuándo no es necesario ni para los resultados, ni para la relación de las tablas, es fiel testigo de esa falta de comprensión. (No puedo decir que es falta de esfuerzo, pero si creo que debes esforzarte un poco más).

Por eso mismo, te doy un query que debiera funcionar, pero lo he reescrito con la nueva sintaxis. Queda en ti intentar entenderlo.

```
select   a.art_descripcion
       , sum(vd.vd_cantidad) Cantidad
       , sum(vd.vd_total_gs) TotalGS
  from ventas v
       inner join ventas_detalle vd on v.ven_nro = vd.vd_nro
       inner join cliente c on v.ven_clien = c.cli_codigo
       inner join articulo a on vd.vd_articulo = a.arti_codigo
group by a.art_descripcion
order by sum(vd.vd_cantidad) desc
```